# How to validate XML with generated c# class from XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml, xml-validation

I want to send a http request from client to local server and on the server I made a query with Linq that returns data in xml
I also have .xsd file and a .cs file enerated from my xsd file that I want to validate my xml with.
I have several questions:

- how can I validate xml with c# generated class?
- how can I return xml from server to client?

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/898525/How-to-validate-XML-with-generated-csharp-class-fr
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your XSD file so I can better tailor my answer to your XSD defined types? Also, SO questions should typically be able to stand-alone (without relying on links to further define the problem). Can you bring the relevant information about this problem from codeproject.com to this question?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I see two separate questions, so I'll provide two separate answers:

**1.) How can I validate XML [with a C# generated class]**

The answer actually doesn't involve the C# generated class at all. Once you've validated the XML, you can deserialize it into your autogenerated class; however, validating XML against a schema doesn't require it. To validate XML against a known schema (assuming you have a XSD file), you can do the following:

```
// define your schema set by importing your schema from an xsd file
var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
var schema = XmlReader.Create("D:\myschema.xsd");
schemaSet.Add(null, schema);
schemaSet.Compile();

// your schema defines several types. Your incoming XML is (presumably) expected to of one of these types (e.g. type="_flashList")
// whatever the expected type is of the XML document root, use that string here to grab information about that type from the schema
var partialSchemaObject = schemaSet.GlobalTypes[new XmlQualifiedName("_flashList")];

// go get your xml, then validate!
// here, SchemaValidationEventHandler is a delegate that is called for every validation error or warning
var myXml = GoGetMyXmlIWantToValidate() as XDocument;
myXml.Root.Validate(partialSchemaObject, schemaSet, SchemaValidationEventHandler, true);
```

**2.) How can I return XML from server to client?**

You can use the 'StringContent' type for your HttpContent

```
var myResponseXml = GoGetMyResponseXml() as XElement;
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   // specify string content, with UTF8 encoding, with a content-type of application/xml
                   Content = new StringContent(myResponseXml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
               };
```